# Piping Read-Host does not wait for input

Tags: powershell

I'm new to PowerShell and want to make some tests. For example this command does successfully wait for user input:

```
powershell -command "Read-Host Test"
```

But if I'm piping "Read-Host Test" to the PowerShell it is not waited for any input. Here is how it looks in the shell:

```
PS F:\> powershell -command "Read-Host Test"
Test: some input
some input
PS F:\> "Read-Host Test" | powershell -command -
Test:
PS F:\>
```

Does somebody know why there is a difference on both commands?

Comment: There is no difference because they are both invalid, none of those lines actually do anything in powershell. What is all this `powershell -command -` ... your in a powershell console, indicated by the `PS` before your F:\ ... why not just type `Read-Host Test`?

Comment: Both are valid commands, admittedly an odd way of doing things but valid commands nonetheless.

Comment: Valid in a cmd prompt, they don't run in a powershell console

Comment: they do for me, powershell v2.0

Comment: Ok it works when I open up console but it doesn't run in ISE for some reason, either way it seems counterintuitive to call powershell from within powershell...

Comment: I have found an error in my example: 'powershell -command "Read-Host Test" | powershell -command -' does not give the command to the pipe but the inserted input. So basically the question is why '"Read-Host Test" | powershell -command -" does not wait for input. I'm editing the question for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
powershell -command "cat test.txt" | powershell -noexit -command -
```

> Executes the specified commands (and any parameters) as though they were
>    typed at the Windows PowerShell command prompt, and then exits, unless
>    NoExit is specified. The value of Command can be "-", a string. or a
>    script block.

Comment: This does skip the input too (the cursor is on the next line).

Comment: it doesn't skip the input, it's just in the next line. Control is not returned to the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Well, cat is an alias of Get-Content, so I'm guessing you have a file named test.txt in your folder that you are running that from. This is a very strange way of doing things, and I'm not sure what you are hoping to accomplish.

As for the differences, the main difference that I could see would be that for one you are running a command directly so it would run in the same namespace as the current session. For the other it looks like you are trying to run a script, kind of, and are not dot sourcing it, so it would run in a protected namespace, which would give you a different result.